# Opengrok indexing with CVS

Tags: indexing, cvs, opengrok

I'm meeting some issues during indexing my project with OpenGrok.
I've checked out my project from CVS and when I try to run indexing with this command

```
./OpenGrok index
```

I've got the following logs

```
Loading the default instance configuration ...
cmontay@cvs.server.com's password:
cmontay@cvs.server.com's password:
cmontay@cvs.server.com's password:
```

In OpenGrok log files, i get the following trace showing me that

```
2013-09-25 16:53:39.691+0200 FINE t10 Executor.registerErrorHandler: Installing default uncaught exception handler
2013-09-25 16:53:40.551+0200 FINE t10 Executor.exec: Executing command [/usr/local/bin/ctags, --version] in directory null
2013-09-25 16:53:40.583+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Scanning for repositories...
2013-09-25 16:53:40.587+0200 FINE t10 Executor.exec: Executing command [cleartool, âversion] in directory null
2013-09-25 16:53:40.595+0200 FINE t10 Executor.exec: Executing command [p4, help] in directory null
2013-09-25 16:53:40.607+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Done scanning for repositories (0s)
2013-09-25 16:53:40.615+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Writing configuration to /var/opengrok/etc/configuration.xml
2013-09-25 16:53:41.094+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Done...
2013-09-25 16:53:41.095+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Generating history cache for all repositories ...
2013-09-25 16:53:41.147+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.prepareIndexer: Done...
2013-09-25 16:53:41.151+0200 INFO t10 Indexer.doIndexerExecution: Starting indexing
2013-09-25 16:53:41.835+0200 INFO t11 DefaultIndexChangedListener.fileAdd: Add: /order/.checkstyle (XMLAnalyzer)
2013-09-25 16:53:41.899+0200 FINE t11 Executor.exec: Executing command [/usr/bin/cvs, log, -N, .checkstyle] in directory /var/opengrok/src/order
2013-09-25 16:53:51.007+0200 FINER t11 DefaultIndexChangedListener.fileAdded: Added: /order/.checkstyle (XMLAnalyzer)
2013-09-25 16:53:51.019+0200 INFO t11 DefaultIndexChangedListener.fileAdd: Add: /order/.classpath (XMLAnalyzer)
2013-09-25 16:53:51.023+0200 FINE t11 Executor.exec: Executing command [/usr/bin/cvs, log, -N, .classpath] in directory /var/opengrok/src/order
2013-09-25 16:54:00.326+0200 FINER t11 DefaultIndexChangedListener.fileAdded: Added: /order/.classpath (XMLAnalyzer)
2013-09-25 16:54:00.327+0200 INFO t11 DefaultIndexChangedListener.fileAdd: Add: /order/.fbwarnings (XMLAnalyzer)
2013-09-25 16:54:00.339+0200 FINE t11 Executor.exec: Executing command [/usr/bin/cvs, log, -N, .fbwarnings] in directory /var/opengrok/src/order
```

How can I ship loggin each time to CVS?

Regards,
Cédric

Comment: I find a solution to workaround my issue. I comment lines linked to SCAN_FOR_REPOSITORY and force value to :
`SCAN_FOR_REPOSITORY=""` but I'm not able to see history in this way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought the Unix shell wrapper script that used to run the indexer is long gone, the problem is still valid.

You did not specify the protocol used for communicating with CVS server. With [pserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006912/what-is-cvs-pserver-mode) it is necessary to `cvs login` first (assuming the `CVSROOT` is set). This will then store the password on disk as described in [GNU CVS manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/Password-authentication-client.html):

> After you enter the password, CVS verifies it with the server. If the verification succeeds, then that combination of username, host, repository, and password is permanently recorded, so future transactions with that repository won’t require you to run cvs login. (If verification fails, CVS will exit complaining that the password was incorrect, and nothing will be recorded.)

> The records are stored, by default, in the file $HOME/.cvspass.

If the server allows it, it might be easier to setup password-less authentication, e.g. using the SSH `pubkey` authentication method. This can be then enabled system wide using the global `ssh_config` configuration file (assuming OpenSSH or its derivatives).

Note that this has to be setup for both indexer and the web application. For the `cvs login` this means that the `.cvspass` file containing the password has to be present in the home directory of the user running the indexer or web application.